# Can't create tables in SSDT after Filestream enabling

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

I have problem with creating tables from **SSDT for Visual Studio 2012** after enabling **Filestream** on Sql Server 2012.

To create I use designer from **SQL Server Object Explorer**.

After click **Update**, error apper:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.   Please correct the
>   following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71565 :: In-lined constraints do not support the FILESTREAM_ON
>   clause. The FILESTREAM_ON clause must be added to the table or the
>   constraint must not be in-lined. SQL71565 :: In-lined constraints do
>   not support the FILESTREAM_ON clause. The FILESTREAM_ON clause must be
>   added to the table or the constraint must not be in-lined.

I have this error even on very simple table like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

What i do wrong? On SSMS this code runs without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix issue in my own project by adding explicit FILESTREAM_ON clause on table level.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) FILESTREAM_ON [StreamName]
```

More info there https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the constraint explicitly within the Create Statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
    (
      [Id] INT NOT NULL,        
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
      [Id] ASC
    ))
```